When saving as a PDF document, Excel uses your name as the author for the PDF doc - How to stop it doing this?
I create PDF invoices for my clients from a template I created in Excel. Rather annoyingly, Excel is auto-populating my name in the 'Author' field for the PDF document. The only way to remove it is to edit the PDF document afterwards and manually remove it from document properties.
However, this causes obvious differences in [file creation date] -> [file modifed date] and I want to preserve these two dates as the same.
I've been looking this up for hours and can't find any solution. Anyone ever find a fix for this? I see it being a persistent problem with many other users too in various forums. It's a trust and privacy issue and I'm surprised this 'feature' seemingly cannot be turned off.

maybe the Author field can be modified using VBA

Have you tried to modify the Author field in the Excel file, or in the Excel settings?

@jstola What would this look like? How would it be implemented? Thank you!

@ComputerUser121212 This is the solution - Thank you so very much!! It was that field that was causing this!! The steps are: From Excel - Click File -> Info ... then right-click on Author under Related People. By removing the name there, it won't save it in the Adobe PDF doc

Two options:

Change the user name in Excel or leave it blank
Look in Excel for something like Settings > General > Personalize
Use your system's Print-to-PDF instead of the Excel Save-as-PDF function
If your system doesn't natively have this feature, install a PDF printer driver.

If you had given us some info about your setup (Mac/Windows/Linux? which version? what version of Excel?), I could give you more specific instructions.

Hi Stacker - Thank you for your suggestions, very grateful.
I have checked the Excel Options -> General -> Personalize your copy of Microsoft Office
There is a 'User name:' field in there, which I eventually managed to make blank by putting a simple space in there. However this still does not remedy the issue with the PDF
I will try the other option Print-to-PDF now :)

I've also tried the other suggestion, Print-to-PDF instead of the Excel Save-as-PDF function. This populates the Author differently (not sure what it's using here - looks like a simple user name) - It also populates the Title field with Book1.xlsx - So unfortunately unless I can get control over that as a user, it's not a solution either.

@Dirkrs On a Mac, the Print-to-PDF dialog offers to edit Title, Author, Subject and Keywords of the resulting PDF. Not knowing what your setup is, I can't offer more specific help.
